# Split lines in several lines by string "\n" and append the line number at the beginning of each line

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I am trying to split each line of a file in several lines by the string "\n" adding the number of the original file at the start of each line of the new file. I explain it in a example:

The original file:

```
   2,5,6,\n6,3,4\n7,8,3
   23,4,1,\n5,5,6,\n2,3,8
```

The file i want to get

```
   1,2,5,6
   1,6,3,4
   1,7,8,3
   2,23,4,1
   2,5,5,6
   2,2,3,8
```

I have tried with the following code but didn't work at all:

```
a=1
while read line
do 
   sed 's/^/tty/' "$line\n" >>file.csv
   tr -s '\n' >> out.csv
   a=`expr $a + 1`
done < file.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```
awk '{split($0, a, /\\n/)};
         {for (i in a) {sub(/,$/, "", a[i]); print NR","a[i]}}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sed and while loop:

```
a=1
while read line; do
    sed -r "s/(([0-9]+,)+[0-9]+)[^0-9]*/$a,\1\n/g" <<< "$line"
    ((a++))
done < file.csv
1,2,5,6
1,6,3,4
1,7,8,3

2,23,4,1
2,5,5,6
2,2,3,8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=1
while read line
do
echo $line|sed 's/\\n/\
'"$a"'/g'>>output.csv
a=`expr $a + 1`
done<filename
```

Manually press enter after sed 's/\\n/\